# How to get a substring that ends before a certain symbol

Tags: substring, stata

One of the variables I have in the file has the following format:

```
Bachelor of Commerce - AD - Accounting-Maj  
Bachelor of Commerce - Finance-Maj  
Bachelor of Commerce - Finance-Maj/Accounting-Min  
BSc with Specialization - Math & Finance-Maj  
BSc in Agric/Food Bus Mngmnt - Agric Business Management-Maj  
Bachelor of Commerce - Management Info Systems-Maj
```

What I would like to do, is to take the first part of the string before the `-` symbol.

For example, from the first three lines I need to get `Bachelor of Commerce`.

I would appreciate if somebody could tell me the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, assuming your variable is named `string_var`:

```
split string_var, parse(" -") limit(1) gen(substring_before_first_hyphen)
```

Answer (score 1):

For future questions, please post attempted code and why it's not working for you. Questions asking only for code are deemed off-topic by some users.

Here is one way:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 2

gen degree = "Bachelor of Commerce - AD - Accounting-Maj"
replace degree = "Bachelor of Something" in 2

list

*----- what you want -----

gen degree2 = trim(substr(degree, 1, strpos(degree, "-") - 1))
replace degree2 = degree if missing(degree2)

list
```

This takes the substring of variable `degree` starting in position 1, and ending in the position (minus 1) in which the first `-` is found. `trim()` will trim any leading or trailing blanks. If there is no `-` in the original variable, a missing will be generated so a `replace` is in place.

See `help string functions` for an array of functions that can be used to manipulate strings.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers using `substring` and `split` are probably better in Stata. I am posting a regular expression solution just for completeness

```
clear
input strL degree
"Bachelor of Commerce - AD - Accounting-Maj"
"Bachelor of Commerce - Finance-Maj"
"Bachelor of Commerce - Finance-Maj/Accounting-Min"
"BSc with Specialization - Math & Finance-Maj"
"BSc in Agric/Food Bus Mngmnt - Agric Business Management-Maj"
"Bachelor of Commerce - Management Info Systems-Maj"
end

gen str=regexs(0) if regexm(degree,"^[^\-]*")==1
list str
```

Comment: (+1) The caret inside the brackets represents negation, which is not a feature that is documented in the [Stata REGEX FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/regular-expressions/) or even the manuals.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Apparently the negation still works in Stata even though it is not official. The best I could come up with following the official rules is this ugly line: `gen str=subinstr(degree,regexs(0),"",1) if regexm(degree,"[\-].*")==1`. Other suggestions?

Comment: I did not mean to imply that it did not work. It certainly does! It's just not documented very well, so I wanted to annotate your code in case anyone else was puzzled.

Comment: Sure. And my intention was not to be defensive but rather to work it out through the "official" code. Certainly it appears to be a documentation issue. BTW, this [link](http://econweb.tamu.edu/jnighohossian/tools/stata/regexp.html) from Texas A&M covers the negation as well as a few other things not mentioned in the REGEX FAQ. Thought it might be a useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
String course = Bachelor of Commerce - AD - Accounting-Maj;
```

if you want to get subString of before '-' character use below line

```
String requiredSubString = course.split("-")[0];
```

in above code split method returns array of stings,  which is separated by '-' character.Then you can get required sub String by its index. so here we are getting 0 index string separated by - character .
   i.e **Bachelor of Commerce**

Answer (score 0):

One could also use the `egen` command with its `ends()` function and the associated `punct` option:

```
clear

input strL string
"Bachelor of Commerce - AD - Accounting-Maj"
"Bachelor of Commerce - Finance-Maj"
"Bachelor of Commerce - Finance-Maj/Accounting-Min"
"BSc with Specialization - Math & Finance-Maj"
"BSc in Agric/Food Bus Mngmnt - Agric Business Management-Maj"
"Bachelor of Commerce - Management Info Systems-Maj"
end

egen new_string = ends(string), punct(-)
list new_string

     +-------------------------------+
     |                    new_string |
     |-------------------------------|
  1. |         Bachelor of Commerce  |
  2. |         Bachelor of Commerce  |
  3. |         Bachelor of Commerce  |
  4. |      BSc with Specialization  |
  5. | BSc in Agric/Food Bus Mngmnt  |
     |-------------------------------|
  6. |         Bachelor of Commerce  |
     +-------------------------------+
```